# Java ArrayList<primitive datatype> consecutive memory allocation only for references?

Tags: java, arraylist, jvm, bytebuffer, primitive-types

I want to allocate an arraylist of primitive datatype objects like int,char etc (not array because it's going to grow in future may be not linearly) but required to be stored at consecutive memory locations in RAM (jvm managed heap). But since when I declare ArrayList for primitive data type for ex. ArrayList for int, internally jvm maps to ArrayList < Integer > type of objects. 

 Now the problem is ArrayList hold consecutive references to objects stored at disparate locations in jvm managed memory space. But my initial idea was to have consecutive storage of actual data objects AND NOT JUST REFERENCES ! But I don't know how to achieve it ? 
One solution I can think of is allocation of large size Byte Array thereby creating a consecutive memory buffer store ! And developer need to manage how to get some int data stored in this manually created buffer (lets us say if we model as 2 bytes/int) at 101 index location if there are 1000 int objects stored in 2000 preallocated bytes !

Same feature is also desirable with complex data types. Although it can be difficult while dealing with consecutive memory allocation for complex objects as one needs to calculate the structure size and preallocate Byte Buffer of (structureSize * No. of Elements Expected)

I cannot think of any other efficient way or solution possible for consecutive allocation of objects (primitive/complex>. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist. Why do you think the current Java memory model is inefficient and you could do better?

Comment: Trove is something I would like to check ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single solution that meets your requirements.

If you want an array-like structure of a primitive type, then you need to use an array of that primitive type or some class that wraps an array of that primitive type<sup>1</sup>.  If you try to implement a custom class, it cannot be generic (on the primitive type) because primitive types cannot be used as generic type parameters.  Therefore, it cannot be an `ArrayList` or any other type derived from `Collection`.

If you want an array-like structure of a reference type then you can either use an array, or an `ArrayList`.

---

In short, if you are not willing to use the wrapper types (`Integer`, etc):

- You have to treat primitive and non-primitive types separately.
- It is best (from an API design and type-safety perspective) to treat the individual primitive types separately.

---

Hypothetically, you *could* create an array-like type that implemented an array of any primitive type, depending on a runtime parameter.  Just define lots of methods / overloads for getting/setting different primitive types.  However, that would not be compile-time type safe, and the API would be *ugly* ... to say the least.

Your idea of using a `ByteBuffer` is essentially the same as the above ... or worse, if you are anticipating that application code does all of indexing and encoding/decoding between bytes and the notional "array" basetype.  (And you'd be better off starting from a `byte[]` rather than a `ByteBuffer`.)

---

<sup>1 - For example, one of the Trove collection classes.</sup>

Comment: byte array is point to start before ByteBuffer. But when you consider storing non-primitive types consecutively both Array and ArrayList are capable of storing consecutive references to objects located in random locations in the memory. It then makes sense in such a case to preallocate byte array of no. of complex objects to store multiply by size of one such object.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is not specified anyway so it could chance.

In the OpenJDK/Oracle JVM, objects are allocated within in a TLAB in order.  Once it is copied into survivor/tenured spaces, in the *reverse order* it is discovered. This means the objects are likely to together in cache.

A simple solution is to use a primitive based collection like Trove where the primitives are actually in a primitive array.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of primitive collections projects, here are some of them:

1. [org.apache.commons.collections.primitives](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-primitives/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/primitives/package-summary.html)
2. [High Performance Primitive Collections](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html)
3. [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)

But be aware, that using such things, you are getting tight to implementation. There is no common primitive collection API.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, is not technically possible due to memory fragmentation issues. Think about it. If your buffer needs to grow, it needs to reallocate the entire ammount of memory, consecutively which would rapidly fragment memory, leaving you running out of memory even though you technically would have enough memory. The closest you can get in regular java is probably java.nio.IntBuffer. But like others have said, you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, true but I am thinking more from an application point of view like implementing storage scheme for column store database where individual column items if stored consecutively will enable huge performance gains while calculating aggregates. The operation cycle for calculating next tuple address is eliminated if cpu knows all columnar data are stored sequentially no matter how big the column size is. Same is applicable with rowstore database where you may need sequential non-primitive storage type for such gains. I hope I am able to convey it.

Comment: If that kind of low-level "optimization" is important to you, you should probably not be using Java in the first place.

Comment: Okay, it seems now Java doesn't give that flexibility for low level optimization ?

Comment: Optimization in Java is generally focused on the VM, rather than the byte code, the Idea being that since the JIT compiler knows which platform and architecture it is running on and/or written for, so is in a better position for optimization. This is part of the write once/run anywhere paradigm. If you only want to run your application on a fixed platform (Windows/x64 for instance) Java provides the JNI mechanism which will allow you to make platform specific low-level optimizations.

Comment: Okay..I will check into JNI. Thanks Mikkel :)